# Alternative to GraphQL long polling on an Express server for a large request?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, long-polling

### Objective

I need to show a big table of data in my React web app frontend.

My backend is an Express server with a GraphQL layer and a few "normal" endpoints.

My server gets data from various sources, including an external API, which is the data source for my current task.

My server has a database that I can use freely. I cannot directly access the external API from my front end.

The data all comes from the external API I mentioned. In fact, it comes from multiple similar calls to the same endpoint with many different IDs. Each of those individual calls takes a while to return but doesn't risk timing out.

### Current Solution

My naive implementation: I do one GraphQL query in which the resolver does all the API calls to the external service in parallel. It waits on them all to complete using `Promise.all()`. It then returns a big array containing all the data I need to my server. My server then returns that data to me.

### Problem With Current Solution

Unfortunately, this sometimes leaves my frontend hanging for too long and it times out (takes longer than 2 minutes).

### Proposed Solution

Is there a better way than manually implementing long polling in GraphQL?
This is my main plan for a solution at the moment:

- Frontend sends a request to my server
- Server returns a 200 and starts hitting the external API, and sets a flag in the database
- Server stores the result of each API call in the database as it completes
- Meanwhile, the frontend shows a loading screen and keeps making the same GraphQL query for an entity like `MyBigTableData` which will tell me how many of the external API calls have returned
- When they've all returned, the next time I ask for `MyBigTableData`, the server will send back all the data.

### Question

Is there a better alternative to GraphQL long polling on an Express server for this large request that I have to do?

An alternative that comes to mind is to not use GraphQL and instead use a standard HTTP endpoint, but I'm not sure that really makes much difference.

I also see that HTTP/2 has multiplexing which could be relevant. My server currently runs HTTP/1.1 and upgrading is something of an unknown to me.

I see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive) that Keep-Alive, which sounds like it could be relevant, is unusable in Safari which is bad as many of my users use Safari to access the frontend.

I can't use WebSockets because of technical restraints. I don't want to set a ridiculously long timeout on my client either (and I'm not sure if it's possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that GraphQL has polling built in https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#polling

In the end, I made a REST polling system.